# swift firebase retrieving data error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My `if` is not working

```
    feelingRef.child("conditions/needsattention").observeEventType(.Value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            print((snap.value?.description)!)
            if (snap.value?.description)! == 1 {
                self.conditionLabel.text = "관심필요"
            }
        }
```

when I print snap's value it prints 1 but `if` is not working!!!

Comment: what you want to do ... you want to count all snaps?????

Comment: the snap.value?.description return a String. So try if (snap.value?.description)! == "1"

Comment: Can you add the relevant snippet of the JSON from your database. Please add it as text (no screenshot), which you can easily get by exporting it from your Firebase Console.

Comment: OK I was doing very dumb mistake... It was String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a `String` type so check with `dynamicType` of your variable

```
print(snap.value!.description.dynamicType)

if (snap.value!.description)! == "1" {
                self.conditionLabel.text = "관심필요"
}
```

Comment: It was String......